# Node.js Electron Applications for Single Core Windows 7 machines are slow on file I/O

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, windows-7, electron

I'm running an electron application on a single core windows 7 machine. It seems whenever I do almost any file I/O with the fs library, the CPU spikes to ~100% for the electron process and it can take up to a minute to perform the file I/O.

One function that is particularly slow is `fs.readFileAsync()`. The file I'm reading is very small, but it seems to take a really long time to perform.

I've also run this exact code on Windows 7 with dual core, Windows 8.1, Windows 10, and Ubuntu 15.10, and none of these operating systems run into this problem, it only seems to be single core windows 7 machines. (So I'm almost positive there is no problem with the code written).

Does anyone know why this could be happening? Is there any solution to this problem? It seems odd that the number of cores affects an electron application's performance. Again this is only Windows 7 though, so single core windows 8.1, or Windows 10 machines do not exhibit this behavior.

Comment: I think we are experiencing this same problem with 99% cpu spikes on single core Windows Server 2012 R2 VMs.  I'll be changing all 4 instances that we have running to multiple cores in several days.. hope it resolves this current snail speed of our Electron apps.

Comment: I'm probably seeing a similar issue with VS Code on startup (which is based on Electron). In my case using the Task Manager to reduce the priority of the Code.exe process that was taking close to 100% of the CPU for hours to Below Normal immediately "fixed" the issue and let VS Code start. Doing the same for another Code.exe process which used the CPU much less did nothing. The culprit seemed to be the initial Code.exe process.

Answer (score 0):

Electron does not handle task like that well in the main process. Electron is also not multi-threaded.

Even though you are running single core, I would recommend using node's "child_process" to run file read/writes(or any heavy task for that matter) outside of electron's main process.  This should solve any strange hiccups or stutters in the app and generally does speed things up.

Also keep in mind that electron is based on chrome and node is based on v8 which is chrome's core.  These things combined make electron very resource intensive by nature and performance is generally the downside of electron.  The upside obviously being able to quickly create cross platform apps.  A 1 core machine just overall is probably not well suited to run even 1 electron app.  We haven't had 1 core machines in what? 10 years?

Answer (score 0):

This is reminiscent of [this](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/29051) issue and others that I have seen.

`require("fs")` in an Electron app doesn't actually get you Node's `fs` module. It uses another version of `fs` provided by Electron. The recommendation from the Electron team is to use `require("original-fs")` when doing file operations.

There is an open [issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/29945) to document this:

> Electron modifies the `fs` module directly to support ASAR files, this can be a performance burden for use cases that do not require ASAR support however and to support those use cases the "original" fs module is available under `require('original-fs')`.

I would try using `original-fs` if you're experiencing slowdown.

Comment: woops, it seems like being single core is an important factor in this question. My answer in that case may not be the correct one...